# WPF: How to bind current date to TextBlock?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I am creating my own calendar month view control. I have just started and I have the back and forward button (to browse months) and a text block to show the current month.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MonthView.Controls.MonthViewControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" 
    d:DesignWidth="450">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="50" />
      <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Orientation="Horizontal" 
        Margin="20,0" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <Button 
          Name="BackMonthButton" 
          Width="30" 
          Height="23" 
          Margin="0,0,7,0" 
          FontFamily="Arial" 
          FontSize="14" 
          Content="◄" />
      <Button 
          Name="ForwardMonthButton" 
          Width="30" 
          Height="23" 
          Margin="7,0,20,0" 
          FontFamily="Arial" 
          FontSize="14" 
          Content="►" />
      <TextBlock 
          Name="DateTextBlock" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          FontFamily="Gulim" 
          FontSize="26" 
          Text="March 2011" />
    </StackPanel>

  </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

I am already stuck as I've never created controls in WPF before. I would like the `DateTextBlock` to display the current month and year. I know I am supposed to bind the `Text` property to something, but I don't know what. Also, when I click the `BackMonthButton` or `ForwardMonthButton`, I would like the `DateTextBlock` to show the appropriate month and year. Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would be to create a custom `MonthCalendar` control. Note that custom controls are very different from user controls because they are look-less. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx)'s Microsoft's starting point for defining custom controls.

For a custom control, you would define the calendar logic along with commands for navigating to the previous month and the next month, and read only dependency properties for making the month/year text available. All of this would be in a code file in a class derived from Control (or a Control derivative).

You would then define a control template to display the custom control. This template would have buttons wired (bound) to the next and previous buttons and the text block would bind to the read only dependency properties.

I highly recommend that you read [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672330334) if you want to make custom controls.

In the meantime, search for WPF month control on Google and you will find lots of controls that you can use or emulate.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the `Text` property to a `Date` property via a converter:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding DateProperty, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}"/>
```

The `DateConverter` codes the rules for converting a `DateTime` object to a text string of your required format and (optionally) the reverse operation for parsing the string to convert into a `DateTime` you can then use in your application.

See [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters) for a complete walk through.

Comment: ChrisF, thanks for the reply. I am familiar with `Converters`. My problem would be the `DateProperty` you have included in your answer. Could you please explain where to define it and how? Thank you.

Comment: @Boris - that needs to be defined on your `ViewModel`.

Comment: I have created a field `DateTime date` and a corresponding property for it, named `Date`, in the code-behind class. Also, I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface in the same code-behind class. Using your code, I have failed to bind the `Date` property to the `DateTextBlock` text property. Do you know where am I making a mistake?

Comment: @Boris - not off hand, sorry. Do some more research on bindings in general. I'm most familiar with Silverlight bindings which are subtly different to WPF.

Comment: Thanks for all the help anyway, Chris. Cheers!